# Error uploading Spark parquet files from Snowflake-S3-Stage to a Snowflake Table

Tags: python, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

EDIT: The error was from Spark's `_SUCCESS` file. Only include parquet files in the SQL query: `pattern = '.*parquet'`

Original:

Can Snowflake load my multi-part parquet files? I have other inserts that work in the same tech-stack but they all use a single parquet file. I'm wondering if the data is being partitioned under-the-hood or otherwise becoming unrecognizable to Snowflake

Here's my simplified query

```sql
COPY INTO database.schema.table
FROM (
    SELECT $1 
    FROM @database.schema.stage/path_to_parquet
)
file_format = (type = parquet)
```

I get this error when trying to copy data in S3 to a Snowflake table:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 100152 (22000): 
Error parsing the parquet file: 
  Invalid: 
    Parquet file size is 0 bytes   
    Row 0 starts at line 0, column
```

If it helps, the command to generate the parquet files looks like this:

```py
spark_dataframe.select("date", "cityid", "prediction")
        .write.mode("overwrite")
        .parquet(predictions_path)
```

And a sample of the parquet files (snappy compression -- a snowflake default)

```
_SUCCESS
part-00000-75a71af4-e797-417a-a2f1-1c31cf9dc891-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00001-75a71af4-e797-417a-a2f1-1c31cf9dc891-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00002-75a71af4-e797-417a-a2f1-1c31cf9dc891-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00003-75a71af4-e797-417a-a2f1-1c31cf9dc891-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00004-75a71af4-e797-417a-a2f1-1c31cf9dc891-c000.snappy.parquet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out while typing this question. My list of parquet files had `_SUCCESS` which is a zero-size file from Spark. This file is causing the `Parquet file size is 0` error.

To fix this, I added `pattern = '.*parquet'` to my query to ignore that file, like this:

```sql
COPY INTO database.schema.table
FROM (
    SELECT $1 
    FROM @database.schema.stage/path_to_parquet
)
file_format = (type = parquet)
pattern = '.*parquet'
```